# C Programing fscanf

Tags: c, text

I've a file that contain this:

`JS;John Silver;27264543`

and I want to get the info separately, like this:

Name: John Silver
Code: JS
Telephone: 27264543

I'm using this:

```
while(!eof(fp2))
{
    fread(line, 1, 100,fp2);
    fscanf(fp2,"%s;%[^;]s,%[^;]d",p.code, p.name, p.tel);    
}
printf("Code: %s\n", p.code);
printf("Name: %s\n",p.name);
printf("Telephone: %d\n",p.tel);
```

`p` is the struct;

But is not working, it is crashing. What I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: You are checking end of file on `fp` but doing fread on `fp2`... It looks like you are trying to read past some prelude to position yourself on the first record, but doing it on the wrong file. Or it could just be totally unrelated and I'm wrong :)

Comment: should fp2 be fp instead (the pointer to the file?).  Whats the point of the fread if you're reading a different file pointer?  A better way would be to run a scanf on 'line' after reading from the file.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of `p`, nor how you initialized it.   Without that information your question is impossible to answer.  What *does* jump out is that you are reading the telephone number as an integer, but trying to print it as a string.

Comment: Sniff, sniff ... smells like homework ...

Comment: Already fix it, but the problem is on the fscanf

Comment: @pmg not homework, wish it was

Answer (score 3):

If `p.tel` is an `int`, then you need to pass a pointer to it into `fscanf`. Try `&p.tel` as the parameter instead.

(However, this is just a guess, because we don't have the definition of the type of `p`.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `scanf()`, not just assume it worked.

```
if (fscanf(fp,"%s;%[^;]s,%[^;]d",p.code, p.name, p.tel) != 3) /* handle error */;
```

---

Hint: Your example line returns 2 from the scanf. The scanf fails at the literal s

```
"%s;%[^;]s,%[^;]d"
/*  HERE ^ */
```

Comment: What you mean with return 2? Thanks

Comment: What's the return type of `scanf()`? An `int`. What does that `int` mean? In case of 0 or more it means the number of assignments made: you need 3 assignments for your program to "work".